# How to Pass Additional Method signature dynamically

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Ok so i have this situation where i need to dynamically open a form, see code below, and, if possible, execute a known method for that form.

#### Open Form Method:

```
Public Sub ShowForm(par As Form, nm As String)
    DoCmd.OpenForm nm

    While IsOpen(nm)
        DoEvents
    Wend

End Sub
```

#### Caveat:

Not all forms will have the same method.  So if possible add an additional optional parameter to pass through the method call, probably as a string value.

### Some examples:

#### Form1:

```
public sub InitItem(id as string)
 ....
end sub
```

#### Form2:

```
public sub InitCategory(id as string)
 ....
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going mad?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not BuildForm(Me.Name, True)
End Sub


Function BuildForm(strFormName, blnRS, Optional strParent = "None", _
                Optional strSubname = "", Optional strParentS = "", _
                Optional NameMod = "", _
                Optional strFormReport = "Form") As Boolean
```

OpenArgs, some notes

```
If Me.OpenArgs & "" = "" Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

astrOpenArgs = Split(Me.OpenArgs, ",")
```

Comment: Did some research in conjunction with the question and was wondering what is the functional use of `OpenArgs` part of `DoCmd.OpenForm`?  Its a solid Variant (ie not Array), but i can sermise several ad-hoc ways of passing an Array without doing so just wondering if you or someone else knew of any limitations to this parameter.

Comment: I use OpenArgs from time to time, but you must remember that they are only available if the form is opened, so of no use for forms that are hidden and shown. You will also need to test whether there are open args, which means building and testing forms with them can be a nuisance.

Comment: Would i use the same type of logic to validate OpenArgs as i would for Console app's args?

Comment: OpenArgs are a string, so it all depends on what you put in the string. I added a note.